# Emulating touch screen on Windows 8 with a Touch-Pad

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, touchscreen, gestures

I am currently running Windows 8 Pro RTM (MSDN) and wonder if there is any way to use the touch-pad as some kind of touchscreen for it or maybe just gestures. I have a Synaptics Touch-pad, searching the internet I found some articles saying about some kind of relation between Synaptics Touch-pad and Windows 8, but I was not able to get info about how to use the gestures or something similar.

Simply the question is, How can I enable Synaptics Gestures for Windows 8 or use the touch-pad as touch-screen (I know it would be a really tiny touchscreen, but I want to try) with third-party Tools or hacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Synaptics Gesture Suite™ Windows 8 for TouchPad™](http://www.synaptics.com/solutions/technology/windows8) enables this on Windows 8, you are not going to find something else because this often involves a driver.  The two images on that page are quite small but I suppose youc an get to see these in the software itself again in a higher resolution. So, if you can manage to get the drivers and the Synaptics Gesture Suite working you can do that...

Comment: Where can I get this for Download?

Comment: @AkshatMittal: Check you manufacturer's site first, then check out their [drivers](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers) page. They also have an [utilities](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/utilities) page to test with. I've also found a page with more specific guidelines of [how the gestures work](http://www.synaptics.com/solutions/technology/touchpad).

Comment: There's also [this driver](http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/notebook-clinic-77/new-hp-touchpad-driver-unlocks-multi-touch-older-touchpad-2702623.html#post44505922) which claims to enable multi touch on any Synaptics device, although that might not have specific Windows 8 support. So, I hope one of these two will help else you'll have to go through some more googling to find the driver...

Comment: I checked Manufacturer site and it din't helped me (drivers on site were more than 8 months old). I currently have SGS 11.4, the site shows that SGS 12.3 includes this gestures but I can not find any download for the same. As far as the other link is concerned, I have a newer version of the same (V7.5). Some gestures (as in the image on hardwarezone.com.sg) are working, but I want the Windows 8 gestures.

Comment: @AkshatMittal: Check AnindyaMaiti's answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/d797c750-cd4d-46e4-9ea8-e55d11db2d10) which has been accepted by a MSFT moderator, it reads that this will release *after* Windows 8 will be released publicly. So, I suggest that you look again the days after the Windows 8 release and if you still can't find it pop up at their site or around the internet by then (like half a week after the release) then you'll need to try to contact Synaptics to inform when it exactly will be released and where you'll need to obtain it...

Answer (score 0):

[Logitech Touchpad](http://gizmodo.com/5950491/logitechs-windows-8-touchpad-loves-gestures-hates-wires)

Above looks like a good start to what you are after. It will allow you to simulate gestures and will be a fully functional mouse. This should work out of the box with W8

Comment: I want to modify (in sense of Software) my current Trackpad to work with Windows 8 Gestures or as a touch-screen to it.